# What should I do if I can only see jdk 17 in my JavaVirtualMachine path and not the other jdk's?

Tags: java, shell, zsh

My ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines tells me I have multiple jdks installed but the path from the finder only gives me jdk 17.0.2.
Due to this, I am not able to provide the jdk 16's path in my Netbeans to add another jdk platform to test and run my project.

Any help would be great :) !!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Finder doesn't hide JVMs for funsies. If `ls` says they exist, they exist. Try as a trick navigating to one of the JDKs you can't find with `cd`, and then typing `open .` on the command line. What happens then? Alternatively, hit CMD+K (go to folder) and paste a full folder. Then just drag from there to the netbeans dialog.

NB: For the future / for others answering this question, you might want to mention in your question that you're using MacOS, or tag it with macos.